# Laravel routes: Breaking when hitting a route in auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I am writing the logic in which the user accepts Terms and Conditions in a separate page and here is the workflow.

1. The user is logged in
2. If they have not accepted the latest Terms and Conditions, show them the `/welcome` page.
3. If they accept them, then there is a link redirecting them to `/accept`

I have got the following routes set up:

```
Auth::routes();

// Temp
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::post('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@postReset')->name('password.request');

// Auth middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // Temp
    Route::get('/discovery', function () {
        return view('pages.discovery');
    });

    // Temp
    Route::get('/welcome', function () {
        return view('pages.welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/accept', 'Auth\LoginController@accept');
});
```

Issue is that when a user is logged in, redirected to the `/welcome` page instead of them clicking on the Accept button to be redirected to the `/accept` route then it breaks with the common message `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

I am guessing it's related to middleware. Any ideas?

**Update**

```
// Auth middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('/accept', 'Auth\LoginController@accept')->name('terms.accept');
    Route::get('/welcome', function () {
        return view('pages.welcome');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['terms']], function () {
        Route::get('/discovery', function () {
            return view('pages.discovery');
        });

    });
});
```

and this is the middleware:

```
class TermsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * @var UserService
     */
    protected $userService;

    /**
     * TermsMiddleware constructor.
     * @param UserService $userService
     */
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$this->userService->hasAcceptedTerms()) {
            return redirect('/welcome');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your pages directory and what you changed within the LoginController.

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: Don't forget the controller that's an important piece to figure out why it's breaking inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::post('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@postReset')->name('password.request');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/accept', 'Auth\LoginController@accept')->name('get.accept');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['terms']], function () {
        Route::get('/discovery', function () {
            return view('pages.discovery');
        });
        Route::get('/welcome', function () {
            return view('pages.welcome');
        });
    });
});
```

php artisan make:middlware Terms

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace;

use Closure;

class Terms
{

    public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = null )
    {
        if( ! $request->user()->accepts_terms ) {
            return redirect( route( 'get.accept' ) );
        }
        return $next( $request );
    }
}
```

add to your HTTP kernel routeMiddleware, 'terms' => YourNewTermsMiddleware::class

Comment: Looking very close to what I am looking for!

Will come back soon

Comment: Okay, /login route is breaking now but in general looks very close what I want to achieve

Comment: No sorry, I think I know what is happening.

Comment: Perfect solution, @Luke Snowden. Accepted as answer!

Comment: Btw, it seems that it currently fails when I redirect user to `/accept`, @Luke Snowden.

Comment: Shall I move it outside?